# Extending admin interface in django

Tags: django

Below illustrated path didn't helped to customize admin interface

IN settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
]
```

IN root
templates is a folder name
there i created a directory admin and inside it base.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

So can anyone suggest. what to do now

Comment: Have you included the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 0):

By creating `<PROJECT_ROOT>/templates/admin/base.html` you overrode Django admin apps `base.html`. But in your template you extended, same template in yours. Since it will create a loop, you would face some errors.

Instead of overriding `admin/base.html`, override `admin/base_site.html`. I believe this is what you want. In your case just rename your template file from `base.html` to `base_site.html` and give it a try. If you face any exceptions please edit your question and add full stack trace.

**UPDATE 2**

After receiving your comment, I have seen that you are giving your templates directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting. This is wrong. You need to specify them in `TEMPLATES` settings as follows:

*This is from one of my projects*

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

As far as I see you have your static files in your templates folder. This is not right. You should put them in separate folder and pass them inside `STATICFILES_DIRS` as you did already. Then your static files will be available for you.

**SUGGESTION**
The previous comments would solve your problem. But I would like to suggest something else.
Django has a template and static file discovery and overriding mechanism.
Your static files and templates are not tied to any app in this solution. 
However, sometimes it's good to tie them up.
Thus if you create an app and inside that app you create templates and static folders and put your templates and static files inside these directories the result will be the same.
In this case you need to add your app name to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: i tried nothing happened. But when i put  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates") inside a dir[] in settings.py it worked but all my bootstrap and others js cs files were not loaded

Comment: I get it now, you should not define your templates directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. It should be inside the place you described in your comment. The problem is you should not put your static files and templates together. You would want to create a separate directory for you static files and mention them in the `STATICFILES_DIRS`. I will update my answer accordingly.